# Non scrollable listview in xamarin.forms

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, custom-renderer

Is there any way I can adjust listview's height as of it's content height in xamarin.forms? I could successfully do it for ios but for android, I applied a solution that leads to slow layout rendering.

`code`

```
public class CustomListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{

...

protected async override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if(Element == null || ((CustomListView)Element).IsScrollable)
        {
            return;
        }

        var view = (CustomListView)Element;
        if(!view.IsScrollable)
        {
            var mAdapter = nativeList.Adapter;

            int totalHeight = 0;
            int listWidth = nativeList.MeasuredWidth;

            int listHeight = nativeList.MeasuredHeight;

            if(totalCount == nativeList.Count)
            {
                //return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.Count; i++)
            {
                global::Android.Views.View mView = mAdapter.GetView(i, null, nativeList);

                mView.Measure(MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(listWidth, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly),
                              MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified));

                totalHeight += (int)(mView.MeasuredHeight / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);

                totalCount = i + 1;
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams param = nativeList.LayoutParameters;
            param.Height = totalHeight
                + (nativeList.DividerHeight * (mAdapter.Count - 1));

            view.HeightRequest = param.Height;
        }
    }
    }
```

This however does not always generate exact height for listview, sometimes leaving space at bottom. Moreover it creates a great delay in laying out the page where list view has been used.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can adjust listview's height as of it's content height in xamarin.forms?

You could using [HasUnevenRows](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.HasUnevenRows/) property to implement this feature :

- HasUnevenRows – true/false value, rows have varying heights if set to true. Defaults to false.

Row heights don't have to be manually set once `HasUnevenRows` has been set to true, because the heights will be automatically calculated by `Xamarin.Forms`.

C# :

```
RowHeightDemoListView.HasUnevenRows = true;
```

XAML :

```
<ListView x:Name="RowHeightDemoListView" HasUnevenRows="true" />
```